# Alternative to multiple Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript

Given a product might have several attributes such as name, price, sku, description and so on - the following will become quite long winded to describe a product model...

```
function Product(data) {

    var productData = data || {};

    Object.defineProperty(this, "sku", {
        get: function() {
            return productData.sku;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
        get: function() {
            return productData.name;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "price", {
        get: function() {
            return productData.price;
        }
    });
}

module.exports = Product;
```

What alternatives are there in javascript for this and how is this normally handled?

Comment: How about [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)?

Comment: You can use a loop to define each property, instead of writing the same function multiple times.

Comment: Why do you use `Object.defineProperty` and setters at all?

Comment: I want them read only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single loop to define all the properties:

```
var self = this;
Object.keys(productData).forEach(function(prop){
    Object.defineProperty(self, prop, {
        get: function() {
            return productData[prop];
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLqv5sac/)

Answer (score 6):

[@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) deserves the points here with [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)-

```
function Product(data) {

    var productData = data || {};

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      "sku": {
          get: function() {
            return productData.sku;
          }
       }, 
       "name": {
           get: function() {
             return productData.name;
           }
       },
       "price": {
           get: function() {
             return productData.price;
           }
        }
    });
}

module.exports = Product;
```

Support is near identical to [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) so there is no real reason not to use this method when defining multiple properties at the same time.

Comment: the correct way. Even tho the "right" answer is more dynamical. had to give yout the thumbs bcs i hate to see the wrong things as right things